# Automatic image rotation based on a logo

Tags: opencv, tiff, watermark, image-rotation

We're looking for a package to help identify and automatically rotate faxed TIFF images based on a  watermark or logo.

We use libtiff for rotation currently, but don't know of any other libraries or packages I can use for detecting this logo and determining how to rotate the images.

I have done some basic work with OpenCV but I'm not sure that it is the right tool for this job.  I would prefer to use C/C++ but Java, Perl or PHP would be acceptable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right place using OpenCV, it is an excellent utility. For example, [this guy](http://www.nashruddin.com/template-matching-in-opencv-with-example.html) used it for template matching, which is fairly similar to what you need to do. Also, the link Roddy specified looks similar to what you want to do.

I feel that OpenCV is the best library out there for this kind of development.

@Brian, OpenCV and the IntelIPP are closely linked and very similar (both Intel libs). As far as I know, if OpenCV finds the intel IPP on your computer it will automatically use it under the hood for improved speed.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel Performance Primitives (IPP) library has a lot of very efficient algorithms that help with this kind of a task. The library is callable from C/C++ and we have found it to be very fast. I should also note that it's not limited to just Intel hardware.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a complex and specialized algorithm that you need.

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching. There's also a demo program (but no source) at http://www.lps.usp.br/~hae/software/cirateg/index.html

Obviously these require you to know the logo you are looking for in advance...